# pod init got uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::XmlMini::IsolatedExecutionState (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cocoapods

mac os

Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.2
ruby -v
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-darwin21]
gem -v
3.3.8

but exec pod init got a error message

pod init
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:184:in `current_thread_backend': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::XmlMini::IsolatedExecutionState (NameError)

```
    IsolatedExecutionState[:xml_mini_backend]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:103:in `backend='
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:201:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `load'
from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case downgrading to ruby30 (from ruby31) solved the issue (using macports):

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo port -v install ruby30`

`sudo port select --set ruby ruby30`

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

hope this helps …