# Uninitialized constant IsolatedExecutionState when running pod install

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I'm currently setting up a new laptop (Intel MacBook Pro) for React Native development and have installed ruby 3.1.2 and Cocoapods using brew. When running `pod install` on my project though, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:184:in `current_thread_backend': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::XmlMini::IsolatedExecutionState (NameError)

    IsolatedExecutionState[:xml_mini_backend]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:103:in `backend='
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:201:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.0.rc3/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

All I can find online is this unanswered question from a few months ago: [pod init got uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::XmlMini::IsolatedExecutionState (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359015/pod-init-got-uninitialized-constant-activesupportxmlminiisolatedexecutionsta)

Any ideas? My Ruby knowledge is zero!

Comment: First result in google. Probably using  newer version of cocoapods which depends on a stable version of activesupport would fix it https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43851

Comment: As far as I know I'm using the latest version of cocoapods? Although I think I have two versions installed - one associated with the system ruby version and one from brew

Comment: Version conflicts could cause issues. Try to make sure that PATH always points to the same version

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my gems, so this cmd made it work again.

```
gem update
```